# Converting a Date into a Serial Number in Excel's Power Query

Tags: excel, datetime, format, m

I'm trying to find a way of adjusting the formatting of a date/time in Excel's Power Query using M code. I need a date/time converted from the Power Query default format `dd/mm/yyyy 12:00:00 AM` to a serial number. This is necessary to avoid any lookup issues as Excel itself defaults to serial date/time values. I've created a custom column featuring three concatenated fields (two text columns concatenated with a date/time column).

This is what I have so far:

`[Team Home]&[Team Away]&DateTime.ToText([#"Date & Time"])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by serial number, you mean the same way that Excel stores date/times, then:

```
[Team Home]&[Team Away]&Number.ToText( Double.From([#"Date & Time"]))
```

Comment: deserves a higher rating, this is impossible to find on the power query documentation for date functions, and should be added there.